# How to make erlang function public?

Tags: erlang

How to make start function public in erlang ?
I am new to the language

```
-export([start_link/3,

 send_xml/2,
 sockname/1,
 peername/1,
 setopts/2,
 controlling_process/2,
 become_controller/2,
 custom_receiver/1,
 reset_stream/1,
 change_shaper/2,
 monitor/1,
 close/1,
 start/4,
 process_request/2]).
```

Comment: Generally, you want to limit how many functions you export. If you're just trying to export everything for testing or because you're writing a throw away module and you're lazy try the compile option `-compile(export_all)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you export your function, it's as public as it can be. And you are doing that with `start/4`.  If you want to export start with different arity (number of parameters), like `start/3` or `start/0`, just add them to your export list.

```
-export([start_link/3,
         start/0,
         start/3.
         send_xml/2,
         sockname/1,
          ....
```

Comment: i am getting following warning when i create the beam file. behaviour gen_mod undefined and when i run my ejabberd server i get following error : beam/beam_load.c(1365): Error loading module mod_http_pre_bind:
  use of opcode 153; this emulator supports only up to 152 and Loading of /home/lanet-rohan/ejabberd-2.1.13/lib/ejabberd-2.1.13/ebin/mod_http_pre_bind.beam failed: badfile

Comment: You are now describing two different (and new) problems.  Second one could be due to Erlang versions (compiling with different one than you are trying to do your loadin), and not defined (?not compiled) behaviour. Please either update your question or ask another one with your workflow and errors.